# Can't find an int in a loop from outside the loop

Tags: java, loops

Can someone tell me why my program can't find the integer `n` outside the loop?

What this program should do is it finds how many lines of text there are in a database and displays it. However, it doesn't display anything since it can't find the value of n.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class kt_5_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("andmebaas.txt"));
            int n;
            for(n = 0; scanner.hasNext(); n++) {}
            System.out.println(n);
        }
}
```

Comment: do you get any error message and if so, post it here !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to not do anything because you are stuck in an infinite loop, as you are never updating the scanner (never calling `next()`). Do this instead:

```
    int n;
    for(n = 1; scanner.hasNext(); n++) {scanner.next();}
    System.out.println(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner's default delimiter is whitespace.
Try

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\n")
```

Comment: ... or `hasNextLine()`, `nextLine()` if OP would want to read entire line, which we unfortunately don't know...